# Не удается открыть docx-файл

Tags: python, telegram-bot, docx

Создаю *docx*-файл с помощью библиотеки *python docxtpl*. 
В шаблоне для создания документа разбросаны тэги, в которые подставляются нужные данные.

Далее документ сохраняется и высылается пользователю в телеграмм.

При открытии полученного документа пользователем с ПК вылазит предупреждение:

> "Не удается открыть файл из-за проблем с его содержимым".

При открытии того же файла с телефона никаких проблем не возникает.

Думал, что эта проблема связана конкретно с отправлением файла ботом. Однако, перед отправлением сохранил сформированный файл и попытался открыть - ситуация такая же.

Буду благодарен любому ответу.

Comment: Как вам помочь без вашего кода, файлов и т.д...? По вашему описанию разве что можно погадать на картах - `вижу проблема у тебя и решить ты её не можешь`. Возможно проблема с кодировкой.